# keeping bootstrap modal active

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

hi how to keep bootstrap modal active after clicking submit button. In my case after clicking submit button it refresh the page so it close the modal. In my modal form i have a textboxes that when you click submit it will save the data in database. Now i have a php code that check the textboxes if their empty it will show/say the error and if not empty it will says success.
Thanks in advance who will help.
This is my code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addtopic" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4>Add Topic</h4>
                </div>
                <form method="POST" action="index.php" role="form" id="saveform">
                <div class="modal-body">

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cCategory">Category</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cCategory" name="category" value="<?php if (!empty($categ)) { echo $categ; }  ?>">
                          </div>        

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cTitle">Title</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cTitle" name="topicTitle" value="<?php if (!empty($topicTitle)) { echo $topicTitle; }  ?>">
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cDesc">Description</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control custom-control" rows="3" style="resize:none" name="desc" value="<?php if (!empty($desc)) { echo $desc; }  ?>"> </textarea>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cDesc">Created By</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cDesc" name="createdby" value="<?php if (!empty($created)) { echo $created; }  ?>">
                          </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
```

```
                                    if($insert = $db->query("
                                     INSERT INTO pncontent (category, title, description, createdby, dateadded)
                                     VALUES ('$categ', '$topicTitle', '$desc', '$created', NOW() )
                                    ")) {
                                        echo "<p class='pull-left'> Topic Save! </p>";
                                    }else {
                                        echo "<p class='pull-left'>Failed to Save</p>";

                                            die($db->error);

                                    }

                                }else {
                                    echo "<p class='pull-left'>All Fields are required</p>";
                                            $desc = $_POST['desc'];
                                            $categ = $_POST['category'];
                                            $topicTitle = $_POST['topicTitle'];
                                            $created = $_POST['createdby'];
                                }

                            }
?>                  
                <button type="submit" name="Sbt" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
                  <button data-dismiss="modal"  class="btn btn-danger">Close</button>           
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you return

```
 echo "<p class='pull-left'>All Fields are required</p>";
```

Add this bit of code to open the modal on page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
       $('#addtopic').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wont this make it that any data inserted in the modal is lost?

Comment: In case the data is lost when you use this you might need to use $_SESSION to store your variables. Try it and if it won't work I'll write you 3-4 rows of code to fix it.

Comment: it doesn't work it still refresh the page that will close the modal